# stream mp3 to website including iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, stream, streaming, mp3

i want to stream an MP3 audio file to a webpage, what would be the best technology to use?

I like the flash controls, but i don't want to exclude the iphone/ipad users

looked at jquery, but is using html5 (if you can give me a link to a good jquery option would be useful)

can anyone suggest a technology we can use, that will accomodate all users, the audio needs to play inline and not move away from the page.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone's version of Safari supports quite a lot of HTML5, [including `<audio>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html). Use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect HTML5 `<audio>` support, and use it if the browser supports it. Otherwise, fall back to a Flash-based player.